# Is there any chess software that tutors beginners?

Tags: learning, software

I am a beginning chess player, and I want to learn more about openings, the middle game, and the endgame.

Can anyone suggest any good chess software that 'tutors' beginners?

Answer (score 16):

The Chessmaster series.

IGN said that `the series has always distinguished itself with first-rate chess teaching tools` and this is the best selling chess franchise in the world. It virtually has no rival in chess teaching software, at least as far as my research goes. Chessmaster doesn't have the best chess engine though, so if you plan on playing professional chess you'll need a better engine after you reach master level.

I owned a copy of Chessmaster 10k and it featured, from what I can remember:

- tutorials from Josh Waitzkin on the basics of chess, openings, endings, tactics, strategy, analysis of his own games
- attacking chess by GM Larry Christiansen
- chess puzzles by John Nunn
- written analysis of 900 famous games
- a searchable database of about 500k games

Comment: +1 I have CM 10K and it's great!

Comment: This advice is no longer useful because there's no way to buy chessmaster anymore.  The last release was in 2007 and it's impossible to find for less than $100.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some:

- Chessmaster (discontinued since 2008)
- Fritz
- Shredder

I know you said just software, but there are a lot of good websites that will teach you openings, mid-games, and end-games.  Here are some:

- http://www.thechesswebsite.com
- http://chesstempo.com/

There are more websites, just google it and you will find a bunch.  I will caution you as a beginner, your focus should be primarily on fundamentals (control of the center, developing your pieces early, castling your king, etc).  You should not worry too much about the opening, mid-game, or end-game for now at least.

Comment: +1 i didn't know about chesstempo before, i find it to be very instructive

Comment: Chesstempo is great, there are many other chess tactic servers, but that is probably the best one.

Comment: What I really love about the tactics on ChessTempo is that after you complete a tactic, you can see comments and tags from other users that help explain why a move is correct.  If you failed to notice that a piece was pinned, for example, the tactic will likely be tagged as "pin" and have a few comments explaining why the "correct" move was better than other moves.  Other tactic sites and apps I have tried don't have these features, and I find I don't learn as much from them.

Answer (score 3):

Four free programs to recommend.
The one program which will take you from beginning through all higher stages is "Lucas Chess" from http://lucaschess.pusku.com.

Another one is "Chessology" with a totally different approach.

If You want the simplest board and AI against then download and use

SlowChessBlitz or Chenard latest version with Blundercheck alert.

NB: They are far more helpful than Fritz 532 and Scid 4.0 which are meant for well-versed novice/hobby/club players.

Good Day
Sunil

Answer (score 2):

One simple answer: **www.Chess.com.**  There really isn't anything in the field that comes remotely close to this website for beginners who want to dig deeper into chess.

Sign up for one of the paid subscriptions and dive into the following features (all broken down into beginner/intermediate or advanced levels)

- Chess Video lectures
- Chess Mentor (interactive try-and-learn lessons)
- Chess Tactics
- Computer Workout (practicing boilerplate/clockwork won/drawn positions vs. a computer)

Comment: Agree with shivsky - chess.com is good, and it has an app for iphone/android. I like the tactics trainer.